# Keil arm startup.s assembly code

Tags: arm, keil

I am trying to understand the keil startup assembly code because it initializes the minimal hardware to work with C language. I am stuck at this line:

```
 IF      PLL_SETUP <> 0
```

What is the meaning of the above line? Specifically, the `<>` symbol? Please somebody help me figure out this assembly instruction.

Comment: What is exactly your question? You're stuck with what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is not assembly per se but a [control directive](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasmref/armasmref_cacbjgdb.htm). <> means ["not equal"](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_Cacbhgfh.htm). So, if the preprocessor symbol PLL_SETUP is not 0, the following block (until ELSE or ENDIF) is passed to the assembler, otherwise it's skipped.